# How to re initstate when Parent widget give different value?

Tags: flutter

```
void initState() {
    var size = widget.screensize;
    double step = size.width * widget.width;
```

The screen size is given by parent widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to override the [`didUpdateWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) method in your `State`. This will run when the parent updates the `widget` property that you get your arguments from:

```dart
@override
void didUpdateWidget(oldWidget) {
  var size = widget.screensize;
  double step = size.width * widget.width;
  //and whatever other code you want
}
```

If you don't want repeated code you can extract that code to a method and call it both in `initState` and `didUpdateWidget`.